# Can't read files into postgres

Tags: windows-7, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We've just set up a postgres 9.3 server on a Windows 7 machine.  If we try to copy data into a database from `C:\dbfeeds\csv.csv` we get the following error:

```
ERROR: could not open file "C:\dbfeeds\csv.csv" for reading: Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

I've been running 9.1 on a separate machine and the solution there was to give `postgres` (the default database user) read/write permissions on that directory.  However this user does not show up in the users on the machine that's running 9.3.

What do I need to do to enable the directory for reading by the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9.3 (and 9.2, when the change was made) runs as `NETWORKSERVICE` by default. So that user must have read rights on the file.

However, in general I recommend using `psql`'s `\copy` or the PgAdmin-III import tool, rather than having the server read the file directly.